# Java Coding - Program hangs when run

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am running into an issue with my Java code and I know where the issue lies, but I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to correct it.  Can someone please help?  This is the line that is causing the issue and I'm not sure how to fix it.  **subtotal = sc.nextDouble();**

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InvoiceApp
{
    private static double subtotal;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "y";

        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        {
            // get the input from the user
            String customerType = getValidCustomerType(sc);
        try
        {
            System.out.print("Enter subtotal:   ");
            subtotal = sc.nextDouble();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            sc.next();
            System.out.println("Error!  Invalid number.  Try again. \n");
            continue;
        }
            // get the discount percent
            double discountPercent = 0.0;
            double subtotal = sc.nextDouble();

            if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
            {
                if (subtotal < 100)
                    discountPercent = 0;
                else if (subtotal >= 100 && subtotal < 250)
                    discountPercent = .1;
                else if (subtotal >= 250)
                    discountPercent = .2;
            }
            else if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
            {
                if (subtotal < 250)
                    discountPercent = .2;
                else
                    discountPercent = .3;
            }
            else
            {
                discountPercent = .1;
            }

            // calculate the discount amount and total
            double discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
            double total = subtotal - discountAmount;

            // format and display the results
            NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
            System.out.println(
                    "Discount percent: " + percent.format(discountPercent) + "\n" +
                    "Discount amount:  " + currency.format(discountAmount) + "\n" +
                    "Total:            " + currency.format(total) + "\n");

            // see if the user wants to continue
            System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    private static String getValidCustomerType(Scanner sc)
    {
        String customerType = "";
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter customer type (r/c):  ");
            customerType = sc.next();
            if (!customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("r") && !customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid customer type.  Try again. \n");
            }
            else
            {
                isValid = true;
            }
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        return customerType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you entered a `double` value? Like `1`?

Answer (score 1):

Program does not hang when it executes:

```
subtotal = sc.nextDouble();
```

rather it simply waits for a double value input from the console. Input a value, and the rest of your program magic should follow.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have an extra call that scans the `subtotal` there.

One in the `try-catch` block

```
try
{
    System.out.print("Enter subtotal:   ");
    subtotal = sc.nextDouble();
}
```

and then another one right before you calculate the `discountPercent`

```
// get the discount percent
double discountPercent = 0.0;
double subtotal = sc.nextDouble();
```

This is what's making you enter the amount twice. Just remove the second call and the program should run fine.

Comment: Thank you!  I figured this out shortly after I posted this question!